# Putting a linked list in ascending order in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to accomplish a function that grows a linked list while also putting them in ascending order at the same time, I have been stuck for a while and gained little progress. I believe my insertLLInOrder is correct it's just the createlinkedList that is messing it up.

Sometimes my output comes out fully and other times it only prints out some of the list.

Anything helps!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *createlinkedList(int num);
node *insertLLInOrder(node * h, node * n);

void display(node * head);
int randomVal(int min, int max);

int
main()
{
    int usernum = 0;
    node *HEAD = NULL;

    printf("How many Nodes do you want? ");
    scanf("%d", &usernum);
    srand(time(0));
    HEAD = createlinkedList(usernum);
    display(HEAD);
    return 0;
}

node *
createlinkedList(int num)
{
    int i;
    int n = num;
    node *head = NULL;
    node *newNode;
    node *temp;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        newNode = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->data = randomVal(1, 9);

        temp = insertLLInOrder(head, newNode);
        head = temp;
    }

    return head;

}

int
randomVal(int min, int max)
{
    return min + (rand() % (max - min)) + 1;
}

node *
insertLLInOrder(node * h, node * n)
{
//h is the head pointer, n is the pointer to new node
    node *ptr = h;
    node *previous = NULL;

    while ((ptr != NULL) && (ptr->data < n->data)) {
        previous = ptr;                 // remember previous node
        ptr = ptr->next;                // check for the next node
    }

    if (previous == NULL) {
//h is an empty list initially
        n->next = NULL;
        return n;                       // return the pointer of the new node
    }
    else {
//if there are nodes in the linked list
// previous will point to the node that has largest value, but smaller than new node
        n->next = previous->next;       // insert new node between previous, and previous->next
        previous->next = n;
        return h;                       // return old head pointer
    }
}

void
display(node * head)
{
    node *p = head;

    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d, ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indent your code. Indentation makes it easier to read and follow along what happens.

Comment: Unless you need the sorted order while growing the list, it would be far more efficient to sort the list after all elements have been added.  You can do a merge sort, with no additional memory, in O(n*log*(n)) time.

Comment: As for your problem, first identify a set of values that will cause the problem. Hard-code these values into your program to test it. Then use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Keep track of the list you create using pen and paper (drawing boxes for nodes, and arrows between the boxes for the links). When the code does something wrong the debugging and the pen-and-paper method combination will make it very easy to see such problems, and where they happen. Hopefully it will also help you figure out how to solve it.

Comment: And generally speaking, when dealing with things like linked lists, I recommend that you always use pen and paper to do the operations first, to make sure they seem to work as they should. Then when you found a way to do in on paper, try to implement it as code.

Comment: Note that your random number generator has misplaced parentheses.  You show: `int
randomVal(int min, int max)
{
    return min + (rand() % (max - min)) + 1;
}` — The `+ 1` should be part of the divisor;  otherwise with arguments 1 and 9, you do modulo 8, which means you'll only get numbers 2..9 from the function.

Comment: In your `createlinkedList()` function (which should surely be capitalized as `createLinkedList()`?), you have `temp = insertLLInOrder(head, newNode);
        head = temp;`.  That's safe and correct but the intermediate assignment is unnecessary; you could write `head = insertLLInOrder(head, newNode);` without any danger of invoking undefined behaviour.  There's no question of modifying `head` before the function is called — there's a sequence point before the function is called and another as it returns.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously in your `insertLLInOrder()` if the first while loop gives `previous == NULL` it means that you must insert at list head, which is not what your are doing.

Just change `n->next = NULL;` to `n->next = h;` and it should improve behavior.

**Taking a step back and perspective**

This is a very simple error, but it is made harder to spot because of the way you wrote your code.

The bug in itself is not very interesting, but it can help to get a higher perspective on why it happened and how to avoid such bugs. 
And, no, running a debugger is not very helpful for such cases! 
Having to run a debugger happens sometimes, but it merely means that you have lost the control of your program. Like having a parachute can be a safety mesure for a pilot, but if he has to use it, it also means that the pilot lost control and his plane is crashing.

Do you know the story of the Three Ninjas Programmers?

**The three Ninjas**

The chief of ninjas orders three Ninja to show him their training level. There is a Noob, a Beginner and a Senior. He asks them to reach a small cabin, on the other side of a field, take some object inside and come back.

The first Ninja is a noob, he runs and jumps across the field with all his speed but soon enough he walks on a (plaster) mine. He goes back at the start line and confesses his failure, which is obvious because his previously black shirt is now covered by white plaster.

The second Ninja shows some practice. You can tell he failed like the Noob on a previous try and that now he is wary. He is very slow and very careful. He sneaks very slowly across the field watching closely everywhere at each step. He gets quite close to the cabin, and everybody believes he will succeed, but eventually, he is also blown by a mine at the last second. He also goes back disappointed to the starting point, but he somehow believes it will be hard for the third Ninja to do any better.

The third Ninja is a Senior. He walks calmly across the field in a straight line, enter the cabin, and goes back without any visible trouble, still merely walking across the field.

When he gets back to the starting point the other two Ninjas are stunned and ask him eagerly:
- How did you avoid the mines?
- Obviously, I didn't put any mines on my path in the first place; why did you put mines in yours?

**Back to the code**

So, what could be done differently when writing such a program?

First using random values in code is a bad idea. The consequence is that the code behavior can't be repeated from one run to the next one.

It is also important that the code clearly separate user inputs (data) and code manipulating that data.

In that case, it means that the `createLinkedList()` function should probably have another signature. Probably something like `node *createlinkedList(int num, int data[])` where the `data[]` array will contains values to sort. It is still possible to fill input data with random values if it is what we want.

That way, we can easily create tests set and unit tests, like in code below:

**Home made unit tests suite**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *createlinkedList(int num, int * data);
node *insertLLInOrder(node * h, node * n);

/* No need to have a test framework to write unit tests */

/* Check_LL is some helper function comparing a linked list with test data from an array */
int check_LL(node * head, int num, int * data)
{
    node *p = head;
    int n = 0;
    for (; n < num ; n++){
        if (!p){return 0;}
        if (p->data != data[n]){return 0;}
        p = p->next;
    }
    return p == NULL;
}

void test_single_node()
{
    printf("Running Test %s: ", __FUNCTION__);
    int input_data[1] = {1};
    int expected[1] = {1};
    node * HEAD = createlinkedList(1, input_data);
    printf("%s\n", check_LL(HEAD, 1, expected)?"PASSED":"FAILED");
}

void test_insert_after()
{
    printf("Running Test %s: ", __FUNCTION__);
    int input_data[2] = {1, 2};
    int expected[2] = {1, 2};
    node * HEAD = createlinkedList(2, input_data);
    printf("%s\n", check_LL(HEAD, 2, expected)?"PASSED":"FAILED");
}

void test_insert_before()
{
    printf("Running Test %s: ", __FUNCTION__);
    int input_data[2] = {2, 1};
    int expected[2] = {1, 2};
    node * HEAD = createlinkedList(2, input_data);
    printf("%s\n", check_LL(HEAD, 2, expected)?"PASSED":"FAILED");
}

/* We could leave test code in program and have a --test command line option to call the code */

int
main()
{
    test_single_node();
    test_insert_after();
    test_insert_before();
}

node *
createlinkedList(int num, int * data)
{
    int i;
    node *head = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        node * newNode = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->data = data[i];
        head = insertLLInOrder(head, newNode);
    }
    return head;
}

node *
insertLLInOrder(node * h, node * n)
{
//h is the head pointer, n is the pointer to new node
    node *ptr = h;
    node *previous = NULL;

    while ((ptr != NULL) && (ptr->data < n->data)) {
        previous = ptr;                 // remember previous node
        ptr = ptr->next;                // check for the next node
    }

    if (previous == NULL) {
//h is an empty list initially
        n->next = NULL;
        return n;                       // return the pointer of the new node
    }
    else {
//if there are nodes in the linked list
// previous will point to the node that has largest value, but smaller than new node
        n->next = previous->next;       // insert new node between previous, and previous->next
        previous->next = n;
        return h;                       // return old head pointer
    }
}
```

As you can see the third test spot the bug.

Of course, you could use some available third party Unit Test library, but the most important point is not the test library, but to write the tests.

Another point is that really you should interleave writing tests and writing implementation code.
This typically helps for writing good code and is what people call TDD. But my answer is probably already long enough, so I won't elaborate here on TDD.

Comment: Thank you so much ! That did the trick, I had a little brain fart there.

Comment: No, problem. Now mark the answer as accepted or even upvote it if you like. That's how SO works. I will add some text to my answer to show a trick I believe is important: when you write code (really any code) also write unit tests. They will immediately catch such bugs and will help you avoid loosing useless time (old programmers can also make such stupid mistakes, so I still write tests after many programming years).